# Multi-knapsack problem with aggregate objective function/objective with a soft limit

Tags: python, linear-programming, or-tools

I am trying to solve a variant of the multi-knapsack example in [Google OR-tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/multiple_knapsack). The one feature I cannot seem to encode is a soft limit on the value.

In the original example, an item has a weight that is used to calculate a constraint and a value that is used to calculate the optimum solution. In my variation I have multiple weights/capacities that form quotas and compatibilities for items of certain types. In addition, each bin has a funding target and each item has a value. I would like to minimise the funding shortfall for each bin:

```
# pseudocode!
minimise: sum(max(0, funding_capacity[j] - sum(item[i, j] * item_value[i] for i in num_items)) for j in num_bins)
```

The key differences between this approach and the example are that if item_1 has a value of 110 and bin_A has a funding requirement of 100, item_1 **can** fit into bin_A and makes the funding shortfall go to zero. item_2 with a value of 50 could also fit into bin_A (as long as the other constraints are met) but the optimiser will see no improvement in the objective function. I have attempted to use the `objective.SetCoefficient` method on a calculation of the funding shortfall but I keep getting errors that I think are to do with this method not liking aggregate functions like sum.

**How do I implement the funding shortfall objective above, either in the objective function or alternatively in the constraints? How can I form an objective function using a summary calculation?** The ideal answer would be a code snippet for OR-tools in Python but clear illustrative answers from OR-tools in other programming languages would also be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working code follows, but here's how you would proceed with the formulation.

#### Formulation changes to the Multiple Knapsack problem [given here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/multiple_knapsack)

1. You will need two sets of new variables for each bin. Let's call them `shortfall[j]` (continuous) and `filled[j]` (boolean).
2. `Shorfall[j]` is simply the `funding_requirement[j] - sum_i(funding[items i])`
3. `filled[j]` is a Boolean, which we want to be 1 if the sum of the funding of each item in the bin is greater than its funding requirement, 0 otherwise.
4. We have to resort to a standard trick in Integer Programming that involves using a Big M. (A large number)

   ```
           if total_item_funding >= requirement, filled = 1
           if total_item_funding < requirement, filled = 0
   ```

This can be expressed in a linear constraint:

```
           shortfall + BigM * filled > 0
```

Note that if the shortfall goes negative, it forces the `filled` variable to become 1. If `shortfall` is positive, `filled` can stay 0. (We will enforce this using the objective function.)

5. In the objective function for a Maximization problem, you penalize the filled variable.

   ```
    Obj: Max sum(i,j) Xij * value_i + sum(j) filled_j * -100
   ```

So, this multiple knapsack formulation is incentivized to go close to each bin's funding requirement, but if it crosses the requirement, it pays a penalty.

You can play around with the objective function variables and penalities.

#### Formulation using Google-OR Tools

Working Python Code. For simplicity, I only made 3 bins.

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp


def create_data_model():
    """Create the data for the example."""
    data = {}
    weights = [48, 30, 42, 36, 36, 48, 42, 42, 36, 24, 30, 30, 42, 36, 36]
    values = [10, 30, 25, 50, 35, 30, 15, 40, 30, 35, 45, 10, 20, 30, 25]
    item_funding = [50, 17, 38, 45, 65, 60, 15, 30, 10, 25, 75, 30, 40, 40, 35]
    data['weights'] = weights
    data['values'] = values
    data['i_fund'] = item_funding
    data['items'] = list(range(len(weights)))
    data['num_items'] = len(weights)
    num_bins = 3
    data['bins'] = list(range(num_bins))
    data['bin_capacities'] = [100, 100, 80,]
    data['bin_funding'] = [100, 100, 50,]

    return data

def main():
    data = create_data_model()

    # Create the mip solver with the SCIP backend.
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')

    # Variables
    # x[i, j] = 1 if item i is packed in bin j.
    x , short, filled = {}, {}, {}
    for i in data['items']:
        for j in data['bins']:
            x[(i, j)] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'x_%i_%i' % (i, j))

    BIG_M, MAX_SHORT = 1e4, 500
    for j in data['bins']:
        short[j] = solver.NumVar(-MAX_SHORT, MAX_SHORT, 
                                 'bin_shortfall_%i' % (j))
        filled[j] = solver.IntVar(0,1,  'filled[%i]' % (i))

    # Constraints
    # Each item can be in at most one bin.
    for i in data['items']:
        solver.Add(sum(x[i, j] for j in data['bins']) <= 1)

    for j in data['bins']:
        # The amount packed in each bin cannot exceed its capacity.
        solver.Add(
            sum(x[(i, j)] * data['weights'][i]
                for i in data['items']) <= data['bin_capacities'][j])
        
        #define bin shortfalls as equality constraints
        solver.Add(
            data['bin_funding'][j] - sum(x[(i, j)] * data['i_fund'][i]
                for i in data['items']) == short[j])
        
        # If shortfall is negative, filled is forced to be true
        solver.Add(
            short[j] + BIG_M * filled[j] >= 0)


    # Objective
    objective = solver.Objective()

    for i in data['items']:
        for j in data['bins']:
            objective.SetCoefficient(x[(i, j)], data['values'][i])

    for j in data['bins']:
            # objective.SetCoefficient(short[j], 1)
            objective.SetCoefficient(filled[j], -100)

    objective.SetMaximization()

    print('Number of variables =', solver.NumVariables())
    status = solver.Solve()


    if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
        print('OPTMAL SOLUTION FOUND\n\n')
        total_weight = 0
        for j in data['bins']:
            bin_weight = 0
            bin_value = 0
            bin_fund = 0

            print('Bin ', j, '\n')

            print(f"Funding {data['bin_funding'][j]} Shortfall \
            {short[j].solution_value()}")

            for i in data['items']:
                if x[i, j].solution_value() > 0:
                    print('Item', i, '- weight:', data['weights'][i], ' value:',
                          data['values'][i], data['i_fund'][i])
                    bin_weight += data['weights'][i]
                    bin_value += data['values'][i]
                    bin_fund += data['i_fund'][i]

            print('Packed bin weight:', bin_weight)
            print('Packed bin value:', bin_value)
            print('Packed bin Funding:', bin_fund)
            print()
            total_weight += bin_weight
        print('Total packed weight:', total_weight)
    else:
        print('The problem does not have an optimal solution.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope that helps you move forward.

Comment: Thanks very much for your excellent and detailed answer! This is pretty much exactly what I need. One thing the code struggles to do is to allow a single item in a bag when that item's value exceeds the bin_funding. Should I amend to something like `solver.Add(short[j] + BIG_M * filled[j] * (sum(x[(i, j)] for i in data['items']) - 1) >= 0`? This would not penalise an overfunded bin if it only contained one item.

Comment: Yes, you can try playing around with the constraints like that. In your example, it seems to be making the constraint non-linear, so watch out for that. Another way to achieve your goal is to make the model pay a heavy price for not filling up with any item. There are many approaches depending on the ultimate goal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I submitted an edit to the answer but I think it is still pending. Uncommenting the `objective.SetCoefficient(short[j],1)` line and setting the weight to -1, and amending the bin shortfall equality constraint to  `solver.Add(['bin_funding'[j] - sum(x[(i, j)] * min(data['values'][i], data['bin_funding'][j]) for i in data['items']) == short[j])` solved the problem of a single item overfunding a bin. Just putting this here for the benefit of others.